# Ignoring empty sheets when importing with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import

I am currently import excel files, containing multiple sheets with the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
input_file = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

However, sometimes there is an empty sheet in the excel file. How can I import my data without having to check manually whether my file contains an empty sheet?

Comment: What is the problem with checking if the sheet is empty?

Comment: Importing using an empty sheet leads to problems later on in the code. Not having to check whether a sheet is empty saves manual work when running the same code on 100s of data files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the sheet is empty it wont takes alot of time to read so you won't waste alot for time on that

You can use the `sheet.empty` to check if it is empty

```py
for sheet in input_file.values():
    print(sheet.empty)
```

## Explanation:

`pd.read_excel` return's an `OrderDict` that contains all the sheets by name

`input_file.values()` will takes all the `DataFrame` objects that each represent a sheet

`print(sheet.empty)` will print if the sheet is empty

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'empty'

Comment: @bjornvandijkman do you change the `input_file` before you calling it? `pd.read_excel` return a `DataFrame`

Comment: No not changing anything. Either way, its not the entire file that would be empty, but a single sheet.